# Minio using java code delete bucket files causing certificate expired

Tags: java, minio

I have using java code to delete more than 10 thousand files from the bucket,
after deleted, minio web page can't login anymore, showing error code 500 and certificate expired.

Minio version: minio-11.1.2

I try to solve it by generating certificate renew it, but it don't works.
Please share some opinion for this.
Thanks.

solving delete files certificate expire problem